# Converting pandas data frame into numpy ndarray

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am using a pandas data frame to clean and process data. However, I need to then convert it into a numpy ndarray in order to use exploit matrix multiplication. I turn the data frame into a list of lists with the following:

```
x = df.tolist()
```

This returns the following structure:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8] ...]
```

I then convert it into a numpy array like this:

```
x = np.array(x)
```

However, the following print:

```
print(type(x))
print(type(x[0]))
```

gives this result:

```
'numpy.ndarray'
'numpy.float64'
```

However, I need them both to be numpy arrays. If it's not from a pandas data frame and I just convert a hard-coded list of lists then they are both ndarrays. How do I get the list, and the lists in that list to be ndarrays when that list has been made from a data frame? Many thanks for reading, this has had me stumped for hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})

print (df)
   C  D
0  7  1
1  8  3
2  9  5
3  4  7
4  2  1
5  3  0

x = df.values
print (x)
[[7 1]
 [8 3]
 [9 5]
 [4 7]
 [2 1]
 [3 0]]
```

And then select by indexing:

```
print (x[:,0])
[7 8 9 4 2 3]

print (x[:,1])
[1 3 5 7 1 0]

print (type(x[:,0]))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

---

Also is possible transpose array:

```
x = df.values.T
print (x)
[[7 8 9 4 2 3]
 [1 3 5 7 1 0]]

print (x[0])
[7 8 9 4 2 3]

print (x[1])
[1 3 5 7 1 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about [as_matrix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html):

```
x = df.as_matrix()
```

Comment: Seems like `as_matrix` is deprecated as of  pandas version 0.23.0, and that `values` should be use instead

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `df.get_values()`, and eventually `np.reshape` it.